# React component with generics, passed a generic array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a generic Slides class that can handle multiple types of slides with generic array of data for it to map over to generate a generic component.

with the following code

```
export interface BaseSlideProps {
    id: string
}

interface Props<T = BaseSlideProps> {
    data: T[]
    Component?: React.FC<T>
}
export const Slides = <T extends BaseSlideProps,>({ data, Component = Slide }: Props<T>) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {data.map((slide) => (
                    <Component key={slide.id} {...slide} />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}


export interface SlideProps extends BaseSlideProps{
    id: string
}
export const Slide: React.FC<SlideProps> = ({ }) => {
    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

I get the following error

```
Type 'FC<SlideProps>' is not assignable to type 'FC<T & BaseSlideProps>'.
  Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible.
    Type 'WeakValidationMap<SlideProps> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<T & BaseSlideProps> | undefined'.
      Type 'WeakValidationMap<SlideProps>' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<T & BaseSlideProps>'.ts(2322)
```

how do I get this to work?

Comment: Consider switching to function declarations for components: https://tsplay.dev/WkDpDw There's loads of other reasons why you should use function declarations over function expressions and `React.FC` that you can find online.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because the caller gets to choose `T`, leading to some calls like:

```
<Slides<{ id: string; foo: string; }> data={[]} />
```

which is unsound, since you'll now be passing a `foo` to your default `Slide` component. Thankfully, TypeScript catches this for us (if not in a somewhat confusing manner). It looks like your component could benefit from overloads:

```
function Slides<T extends BaseSlideProps>(props: { data: T[]; Component: React.FC<T> }): JSX.Element;
function Slides(props: { data: BaseSlideProps[] }): JSX.Element;
function Slides({ data, Component = Slide }: Props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {data.map((slide) => (
                    <Component key={slide.id} {...slide} />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

If there was no component passed, we only need BaseSlideProps for our data. Otherwise, we use the prop types of the component for the data.

You could also change `Slide` into a function declaration:

```
function Slide() {
    return <div></div>;
}
```

But that feels like cheating and ignoring the underlying issue.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocpAD0ljmADsYkpN0k4AhFAZyQDKAG2AATJAAUcYXnADe5OEoaiAXHF4woTAOYUAvpSYs2HOFIgz5i5aJQwU6nv2FjJ03gG0AuhWVwAYVxIRiRmAH51ZHQYADoAMQCAHmdBEXELGQA+A0pMAFdGDGAIRjhXcV4kgBU4GhZGUVlUivdLXiyACjAPdTk4Owd1ap9SQODSsJgo4jjEmqy4fQBKdQApAQANWIBRISQQKYoCopgSstbebt75AftHbj40t0yvbyXVuA3tvYOj8hOxVK5XSSCu-UGKAANONwJNmHAALwgtxLdSvZbWfxEGD5KBlTo2fxKJKiYAANyyROJ-lJFKpNMZyjkkNiIBQYE6nV4oMxiMWhKZQuUSSCcNCCIA1kgAJ6IuQ8tyxMT6eSxdWK8SqgD0DOFxOWy0M+rgSW1ZMp1Np5vp1OWuSotGg8GMrHYaE4rVedWoDSajxcoO9ckMjro8DQpU0KPEMxiCWSXo8i2RnRDfMWCmxSFx+NNFqyZoLBgo5G12rgKEYMrgEEwcBgAAswZwUEJeBA4AB3aCSssVwFnYGtNP6dRJ9qYhTluCD84xpCjvorawzufD0Gjqf92eFIEXTfbmfZ3NlOmUov0igzwxAA)